# Where can I find rules on which Stack Exchange community site my question should be asked on?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Are there any guidelines on how to pick the community for a specific answer?

I realise the name is meant to be self-explanatory, like ["Vi and Vim"](http://vi.stackexchange.com), [Role Playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) or [Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/), but it's not always that obvious.

After some digging I've only discovered that the `StackExchange` drop down menu offers one-line, brief descriptions but still it doesn't clear some doubts user might have…

For instance I don't see too much difference between:

[Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) - "For users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems"

[Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) - "For system and network administrators"

and

[Super User](http://superuser.com) - "For computer enthusiasts and power users"

Plenty of Linux or Unix related questions lands in the latter two. On the other hand Windows-related questions mostly go to the last one. As if that is not enough [Apple](http://apple.stackexchange.com) and [Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) have their own communities. A generic [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) question might actually go under any of the above, but not just, let's say Apple only, because it's being asked by a Mac user.

Other examples:

- [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) - "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf"
- [Data Science](http://datascience.stackexchange.com) - "For Data science professionals, Machine Learning specialists, and those interested in learning more about the field"
- [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com) - "For students, researchers and practitioners of computer science"
- [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com) - "For scientists using computers to solve scientific problems"
- [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) - "For peer programmer code reviews"

or:

- [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) - "For speakers of other languages learning English"
- [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com) - For linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts"

But I'm sure you could find more such cases depending on a question.

As a result, a lot of questions simply land on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), and in fact I'm not even sure if this one shouldn't be posted there... Also users looking for existing answers might miss some just because it would be in the other community.

So this is a question for relevant references if those exist but maybe it's also worth considering:

1. Merging some of the smaller communities (also I think a tag should say well enough if this is related "Vi", "Vim", or "Emacs")
2. Introduce some features like:

   - "Move to (or share with) relevant community" suggestions
   - Voting on those
   - And finally, when quorum reached or owner agreed - moving (or sharing) of such questions between communities

Should we do this to better organise new and already existing questions?

Comment: Moving between sites is already possible (it's called migrations here). (You've got the description for ELL wrong in your post.)

Comment: @Mat, I'd like to know more about those `migrations`. Would you share how to do that or a link? Does it allow to post same question into multiple communities?

Comment: Try "migration" in the search box, you'll get lots of info

Answer (score 8):

Every site has a help center entry that defines what's on and off topic for that community.

It's found in `http://<site>.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic`. Here's an example from [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/): https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

That page should have all the information you need, and if it doesn't, feel free to raise it on the site's respective meta and ask whether or not your question is on topic with them.

Comment: Yes, but for first time user it's rather laborious research to undertake fist before posting. And to me that's why people simply don't do that which results in questions landing in the first found community.

Comment: You also have the [tour] on all sites that allow you to gain a quick and simple overview on what's on-topic. But if you really want to be sure, the [help] is the right place to go.

Comment: thanks for that, it's quite useful. On the other hand it's yet another scattered place to do research…

Comment: @msciwoj Would you prefer a giant 5MB page that tells you what each and every one of the 100+ sites we have are all about, including what you should and should not ask about? It's not really practical, you know.

Comment: of course not! All I am saying there has to be some better way. Look, the fact that I've only learned all that from you best proves that there's a room for improvement here… (And yes, I did a quick research)

Comment: @msciwoj "*for first time user it's rather laborious research to undertake first before posting*" If you have any ideas to make it easier, please post a new feature-request or discussion outlining it. Currently I see no way for anyone to learn how a specific sites works without reading about it first - in the Tour, Help Center, and viewing some questions and answers. The information is there, so all is needed is to read it. If there is something someone does not know, then they need to obtain that info, on the internet that involves *spending some time*, whether reading or watching a video :)

Comment: @James, I'll think about it. Like I wrote, sharing the post between multiple communities (with some extra governance) could be a way to get around that. Merging them or building a hierarchy could also help. Another idea would be to identify overlapping or related communities and display suggestions, kind of "if you're asking about XYZ consider posting this under ABC", "if your question is more related to the administration etc.. please use community DEF"…   Anyway, sharing makes most sense to me - at the end of the day that's why tags were invented - you rarely want to only use one classifier

Comment: hmm, this one `meta.stackoverflow.com` does not, I think… and for instance now I am still not sure where should this question go: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359586/stackoverflow-markup-for-html-colors? Here: `meta.stackexchange.com` or maybe there: `meta.stackoverflow.com`…?

Answer (score 1):

Every site has a tour page that explains the basics of each site. The contents may vary as it will change as you go to different sites. For example, the MSE tour page says that the following is on topic here:

> Specific issues with the software that powers the Stack Exchange network

and

> Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered using this software

Where did I get the information? Go to the top black bar and click on Help. There should be three different options to choose from. One says tour. Click on tour and you will get redirected to the tour page for that specific SE sites. Of course, the Help Center and summary will also help. Hope this helps you and it works!